# Vulkan Raytracing: Problem with procedurally (yet to be) generated sphere

Tags: vulkan, raytracing

I wanted to upgrade my Cornell box with a procedurally generated sphere but did not get far: the intersection shader is not being invoked at all (as evidenced by lack of messages from debugPrintfEXT() in that shader)

I've:

1. added a BLAS for the sphere and another
   VkAccelerationStructureInstanceKHR in the TLAS for this new BLAS:
   (instanceShaderBindingTableRecordOffset=0 for existing the Cornell
   Box which works and instanceShaderBindingTableRecordOffset=1 for the
   sphere).
2. added a Hit Group of type
   VK_RAY_TRACING_SHADER_GROUP_TYPE_PROCEDURAL_HIT_GROUP_KHR, with
   VK_SHADER_STAGE_CLOSEST_HIT_BIT_KHR and
   VK_SHADER_STAGE_INTERSECTION_BIT_KHR shaders.
3. made sure that the hit group count is incremented by 1 In SBT
   creation calculations.
4. tried different values (0..7) for sbtRecordStride in the RayGen
   shader's traceRayEXT(..., 0, ?, 0, ...)
5. Made the sphere extremely large to ensure a hit.

What else could I try?